# Call java adapter from client ibm mobile first worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I've created a java adapter "myadapterjava" on mobile first 7.0.
below the procedure

```
@POST
@Path("/myprocedurejava")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public JSONObject myprocedure(String param){   

 JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("firstName", "John")
 .add("lastName", "Smith");
 return value ;
}
```

I'm trying to call it from javascript using:

```
var urlToInvoke = '/adapters/myadapterjava/myprocedurejava';
    var timeOut = 20000;
    var param = JSON.stringify(mydata);

    var procedure = WLResourceRequest.POST;

    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(urlToInvoke, procedure, timeOut);
    resourceRequest.send(param).then(function(data) {
        console.log("OKOKOK");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("KOKOKOKO");
    });
```

In this way I have the onError call and the status of the error is 415.
Where I'm wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the @Produces to `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`